# Let $\{a_n\}$ satisfy $a_1=1, a_{n+1}=\sin(a_n)$, find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(a_n)}{\log(n)}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

This is question 24 of a Brazilian Olympiad multiple-choice test (for undergraduate students) that you need to pass in order to qualify for the main national math Olympiad. The problem is as follows: Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers recursively defined by $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=\sin(a_n)$. Find the value of $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(a_n)}{\log(n)}.$$ The answer choices are

A) 0

B) $-\frac{1}{2}$

C) $-1$

D) 1

E) $-\infty$.

I tried using $\sin(x) > x - \frac{x^3}{6}$ to simplify the nested sine functions, but that didn't work. I also attempted to find the Taylor expansion of the nested sine function, but I could only get up to the $x^3$ term and the other terms were too difficult. My feeling is that since $a_n \to 0$ and $\log$ approaches $-\infty$ quickly while $\log(n)$ approaches $\infty$ very slowly, the answer will be E.

It's worth noting that this exam has 25 problems to be completed in 3 hours, and while there are many non-trivial problems, they shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: If you just need a fast answer rather than a rigorous proof, take $a_n\sim Kn^L$ so$$\frac{L}{n}=(1+1/n)^L-1\sim-\frac16K^2n^{2L}\implies L=-\frac12.$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more? I dont't understand why you start with $\dfrac{L}{n}$ and how you go from $(1 + 1/n)^L-1$ to $-\dfrac{1}{6} K^2 n^{2L}$

Comment: My point is both sides of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1=\operatorname{sinc}a_n-1$ have a convenient asymptotic form, viz. $\frac{L}{n}=-\frac16a_n^2=-\frac16K^2n^{2L}$,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easy to see that $a_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ and thus
$$\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_n}=\frac{\sin a_n-a_n}{a_n}\sim -\frac16a_n^2, \qquad n\to\infty.$$

By [Stolz-Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem_for_the_0/0_case), we have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log a_n}{\log n}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log a_{n+1}-\log a_n}{\log(n+1)-\log n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\log\left(1+\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_n}\right)\\
&=-\frac16\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n^2.
\end{align*}
So, we only need to compute the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n^2$. Using again Stolz-Cesàro theorem we obtain
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n^2&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{\frac1{a_n^2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1-n}{\frac1{a_{n+1}^2}-\frac1{a_n^2}}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{\frac1{\sin^2x}-\frac1{x^2}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2\sin^2x}{(x-\sin x)(x+\sin x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^4}{\frac16x^3\cdot (2x)}=3.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log a_n}{\log n}=-\frac16\times 3=-\frac12.$$